# Unpin FTP folder from Windows 10 Quick Access

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp, windows-10

I've pinned an FTP location to the Quick Access menu in Windows 10 Explorer, but now cannot unpin it.

To replicate:

1. Browse to an FTP location in Windows Explorer
2. Right-click "Quick Access"
3. Select "Pin current folder to Quick access"
4. Right-click the newly pinned folder

You should see that there is no option to unpin the folder. The context menu only offers the (greyed out) option to "Expand".

Notably, this pin only appears in Explorer and not in the jump lists (for example by right-clicking Explorer from the task bar).

How do I remove this pin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't find a user friendly way either.

Anyway, the pinned folders are stored in:
`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

I.e. typically in
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

Just delete the files from there.

Answer (score 7):

I found an easier way to do it: we get the greyed "Expand" context menu only for FTP links. If, in the Quick Access folder, we multi-select (holding the Ctrl button) the FTP link(s) plus another normal one, then the normal context menu is displayed and we can unpin them all at once.

Comment: It's the easiest way to unpin an FTP link on the quick access.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment because of reputation but I'd like to point out that Martin answer is also helpful if you move your Download folder to other location. I moved mine from `C:\User\Name\Download` to `D:\Download` but Quick Link stuck at the first one and couldn't be unpinned.

The solution was to:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Paste `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. At this point you can delete everything in there (there should be only a bunch of files with `.automaticDestinations-ms` extension) or - if you want to delete only one - open them in `Notepad`; the file is mostly-giberish but it also shows path.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to Unpin the stuck FTP item without completely clearing the Quick access listing. Click Quick Access, and in the right pane select multiple items (the stuck FTP link and another working one), right-click and click Unpin from Quick access.

Source: Fix Cannot Unpin FTP Links From Quick Access In Windows 10? http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unpin-ftp-links-stuck-quick-access-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following string into the Explorer address bar:

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

Delete all the files in that folder.